# Bidirectional association, what's better?

Tags: design-patterns, optimization, associations, setter

Not really a problem, but I wondered many times about how to implement double association in code...

Let's have an example. A man car wear a single hat and a hat can be on a single man. But if the man wears the hat, the hat's owner have to be that man.

Here is how I used to do it (Java) :

In *Character* :

```
public void setHat (Hat hat) {
    Hat former = this.hat;
    this.hat = hat;
    if (former != null && former.getOwner() == this)
        former.setOwner(null);
    if (hat != null && hat.getOwner() != this)
        hat.setOwner (this);
}
```

And in *Hat* :

```
public void setOwner (Character c) {
    Character former = this.owner;
    this.owner = c;
    if (former != null && former.getHat() == this)
        former.setHat(null);
    if (c != null && c.getHat() != this)
        c.setHat (this);
}
```

This way, the man's hat and the hat's owner are always coordinated.

But... that sounds a bit clumsy to me. What's the better way to implement this kind of conditional setter, please ? It's very useful to me.

(if I made mistakes, that's just because baguette ok? ^^)

UP, please ^^

Comment: Why do you say it's "clumsy"? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some design principles apply. *Encapsulation* means you won't leave your either object (hat or man) in an inconsistent state. I think you're achieving this with your solution.

A second principle is called the *Law of Demeter*, which exists to make maintaining software easier by reducing coupling. It states that a method should only use

- instance fields of its class
- parameters
- objects that it constructs with `new`

The intention is to have the method avoid asking another object to give it a part of its internal state to work on. Since a Hat has an instance field of type Man, and vice-versa, it's probably not so bad.

A design pattern that could apply (if you wanted to take away the redundant code) would perhaps be [Mediator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern). Here's a part of the solution (you could really just use a class that handles the management, without going all the way with the Mediator pattern):

[image]

The down-side of this is that `Man.setHat` and `Hat.setMan` are public methods and could be called by anyone without respecting the "global" conditions that you can program your Mediator to do. For example, some other class could call `setHat(h)` on several different `Man` objects.

In this case, you could use assertions (design by contract) to make sure that anybody calling those methods would not violate so-called invariants, e.g., a precondition to `Man.setHat(h)` is that `h.man == null OR h.man == this` (it's not already being worn by another Man). However, I'm not sure that doing all that is less *clumsy* than your current code.

Finally, you can apply the *KISS* principle where you don't use bi-directional associations. For example, if a `Hat` has to know which `Man` it's on (perhaps less likely to occur), then you implement a `Hat.getMan()` method that iterates through the list of known `Man` objects, searching for itself (or use some other class to find it for you if you're worried about cohesion). Performance is the reason you may not want to do that.

A related question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/200949/class-design-with-bi-directional-relationships

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to keep a consistant model, and this problem occured many times when I am doing games (a card which has to know which tile it is on, and the tile which has to know what it has on it, etc...). This is a bit clearer to me now. I just have a last question : are bidirectional associations BAD ? I'm asking because surprisingly, I didn't see the question on the internet.

Comment: In design questions, I avoid asking if things are good or bad. Choices have consequences. If you choose bidirectional associations, such are the consequences.